# Excel conditional formatting: set a custom "zero" value in data bars

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

i would like to set up a data bar in conditional formatting in excel (2013) like this:

[image]

however, i haven't been able to select a custom value as the cut-off or "zero" value separating negative and positive values. what i would like to achieve is to show values larger than, say, 60% with a bar extending to the right, and values smaller than 60% with a bar extending to the left.

i don't think excel supports setting a custom "zero" value, so maybe someone knows a hack for this?

my use case is this. i am tracking product usage rates. i know how much of each type of product i have in stock and how much there was after last shipment. based on how much time passed since last shipment, i can estimate how much i should have currently in stock. if the value is below the threshold, that means that usage estimations are underestimated and that on the next shipment more of that particular product should be ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i managed to achieve that by using two cells for the data bar and tweaking the formulas slightly. this is the effect:

[image]

**formulas:**

first column:
`=IF(value<=threshold,threshold-value,"")`

second column:
`=IF(value>threshold,value,text(value,"#0%"))`

**conditional formatting:**

negative values:

[image]

positive values:

[image]

in this case my threshold was 70%

Comment: i will accept my own answer unless someone else comes up with a way to do it in one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, while I have no idea why you would want to show a value of less than 0.6 going to the left, here is how you do it:

1. Click on the axis of your table, until all of the axis labels are selected
2. Right Click -> Format Axis
3. Change Axis value to "0.6"

[image]

4. Viola!

[image]

Comment: i am not using charts but conditional formatting with data bars. also, i updated my question to explain why i would need this.

Comment: Ahhh, I misunderstood!